# Read-only on an SQLite database which is being modified by another program

Tags: sqlite, concurrency

I wrote a program that has an SQLite database, modifying it every few seconds.

Now I want to write a small gadget program that would just read a bit of info from that database (read-only) and display it.

Can the second program open the database as "read-only", while the first program might be modifying it?
Is using `Read Only=True` when opening the database enough?
Or do I have to make a copy of the SQLite file, or something?
I did not find any tip about this on [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org).

The second program does not need real-time info, it can be a bit outdated.

Comment: [SQLite write locking documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html#section_3_0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [WAL Mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

> WAL provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a
>   writer does not block readers. Reading and writing can proceed
>   concurrently.